# Why is my REST API returning bad data on AWS but not on the local machine?

Tags: rest

Interesting bug(?) in some my code. Using this query as an example:

```
String qry2= "select schoolDistrict, COUNT(H) as number from House H where termsSale like \'%VA%\' and closedDate>=\'2019-01-01\' group by schoolDistrict order by number desc";
```

On my local machine I get correct data, such as:

```
[["3-Widefield",215],["49-Falcon",203],["11-Colorado Springs",152],["20-Academy",131],["2-Harrison",100],["8-Fountain",82],["38-Lewis-Palmer",37],["Re2-Woodland Park",20],["12-Cheyenne Mountain",18],["60-Pueblo",9],["28-Hanover",6],["70-Pueblo",5],["14-Manitou Springs",4],["Re1-Douglas",3],["Rj1-Calhan",3],["22-Ellicott",3],["Re-1-Canon City",2],["Re-2 Fremont",2],["Re-4J-Limon",2],["RE1-Cripple Creek/Victor",2],["Other",2],["60Jt-Miami/Yoder",1],["R-1-Jefferson",1],["23Jt-Peyton",1],["RE-2-Eaton",1],["Re-2-Park",1]]
```

However, on my AWS instance, when I hit the API there after I upload it, I am getting random pieces of data from the database inserted in the feed:

```
[["3-Widefield",729],["49-Falcon",678],["11-Colorado Springs",467],["20-Academy",416],["2-Harrison",314],["8-Fountain",274],["38-Lewis-Palmer",121],["12-Cheyenne Mountain",69],["Re2-Woodland Park",54],["70-Pueblo",33],["Ceiling Fan, Forced Air, Natural Gas",20],["Ceiling Fan, Central Air, Forced Air, Na",19],["28-Hanover",18],["60-Pueblo",17],["14-Manitou Springs",17],["Forced Air, Natural Gas",17],["Central Air, Forced Air, Natural Gas",17],["22-Ellicott",16],["Re1-Douglas",15],["Ceiling Fan, Central Air, Forced Air",13],["23Jt-Peyton",12],["Other",10],["RE1-Cripple Creek/Victor",10],["Forced Air",10],["Central Air, Forced Air",9],["Ceiling Fan, Forced Air",8],["Re-2 Fremont",8],["Rj1-Calhan",7],["60Jt-Miami/Yoder",6],["Re-2-Park",4],["C-1-Elizabeth",4],["100J-Big Sandy",3],["Natural Gas",3],["200-Elbert",3],["Re-1-Canon City",3],["Re-4J-Limon",2],["Central Air",2],["Central Air, Natural Gas",2],["Ceiling Fan, Forced Air, Natural Gas, Wo",1],["Baseboard",1],["28J-Arapahoe",1],["R-1-Jefferson",1],["None",1],["Ceiling Fan, Central Air, Forced Air, Ho",1],["Baseboard, Ceiling Fan, Propane, Radiant",1],["Central Air, Forced Air, Hot Water, Natu",1],["Hot Water, Natural Gas",1],["Ceiling Fan, Natural Gas",1],["Attic Fan, Forced Air, Natural Gas",1],["RE-2-Eaton",1],["Ceiling Fan, Central Air",1],["Ceiling Fan, Electric, Propane, Radiant ",1],["Ceiling Fan, Forced Air, Propane, Wood",1],["Ceiling Fan, Central Air, Natural Gas",1],["Central Air, Hot Water",1]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the instance is not in the same timezone as your local?

Since you have this parameter in `closedDate>=\'2019-01-01\` in your query. There might be more data matching.

Comment: Thank you. I should clarify the AWS instance has the more complete dataset. The local machine is just a test dataset so the numbers will differ. 

When I query the database on AWS, I don't see any junk data in termsSale, so I am unsure how it is pulling in that info (which is in another field entirely).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this question: it turned out I DID have bad data from a botched upload. Thank you for reading the question!